# Why is Eloquent returning a different result if retrieving All and using a where clause?

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

When I use the following retrieve:

```
$items = Item::All()->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
```

I get (no idea of what the '0' and '2' identifiers are):

```
"items": {
        "0": {
            item1data
        },
        "2": {
            item2data
        }
    }
```

But when I use:

```
$items = Item::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

I get the following array:

```
"items": [
        {
            item1data
        },
        {
            item2data
        }
    ]
```

The second is what I need, so I can send it back as a Json response, but I'm curious of why the results are being different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you're loading all records from DB and then filtering the collection using the [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-where) collection method. Which is a terrible idea, by the way.

In the second example, you're getting only records you want using query builder [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) method.

That's why the format is different. You should use only the second approach.

Comment: It's weird because I was using this for a GET Request, and the first option was returning the array, just like the second option. Then it broke somehow after a recent 'composer update' (laravel version has always been 5.4.* for this project). But what you say makes sense.

Comment: @MahdiYounesi I never was against high-quality answers, I even upvote concurrent answers if they are good. But I will be always against stealing. When you'll learn how to make a good answer without stealing, you'll be fine. If not, the account can be banned. You're not the first guy here who tries to earn some points by doing nasty stuff.

Comment: @Jk33 I recommend you just forget about the first approach unless you want to get all the records from DB.